# DevicePolicyManager locknow not in an activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hoping someone can help me, as I have been stuck on this for days. I am trying to lock my device remotely when a PUSH notification arrives with a specified keyword. Else, display the message in a notification.

It correctly displays the notification but never locks the screen when the keyword is sent, nothing happens, nothing is logged. 
I have confirmed the string is correctly read as I previously set it to display a custom notification if the message contained the keyword.
The app definitely has admin privileges and I can lock the screen using the same code inside an activity ... is there something else I need to do to get this to work in the gcmintentsevice ??

here is my gcmintentservice code

```
package library;


import com.test.LoginActivity;
import com.test.R;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the actual handling of the GCM message.
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {


    String messagereceived; 
    String Password = "LOCK";

    ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "test";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {



        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                // Post notification of received message.
                messagereceived = extras.getString("message");

                if(messagereceived.equals("LOCK")){
                    gcmaction();
                }
                else{
                     sendNotification("Message: " + extras.getString("message"));
                     Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + extras.toString());
                }

            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

  //lock method 
  private void gcmaction() {

      mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
      mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);

      boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin);
      if (active) {
      mDPM.resetPassword(Password,DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
      mDPM.lockNow();

      }
      else Log.i(TAG,"Not an admin");

  }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("ParentalKontrol")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put any log into `gcmaction()` if this is calling or not.

Comment: Ok , I think I may have narrowed down the issue ... I rebuilt the AVD and tried again , this time it did lock but I could only get it to work once. Looking at the logs I am seeing the following ... 10-10 09:49:38.363: E/StrictMode(453): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.10-10 09:49:38.363: E/StrictMode(453): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called

Comment: Actually might have been premature the above error only happened once .. if I delete and rebuild the AVD it works but once only, everytime. No errors logged ... very frustrating!!

Answer (score 0):

Your my_admin.xml contains below?

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: Yes I checked this, to make sure I tried calling a test notification method and to display a custom string value. Then I sent a message with the keyword and it displayed the custom message, ie: the if statement was true ... any other message went to the sendnotification method

Comment: When you receive notification at that time device is admin already? have you confirmed it?

Comment: Add a log into method to make sure that its calling...

Comment: yes , it is definitely admin ... i use the same code to test inside an activity and can lock the screen

Comment: logging if admin or not here else Log.i(TAG,"Not an admin");

Comment: Yes, security_policy.xml is defined with force-lock and reset-password